# Broadcom iSCSI HBAs missing in vSphere

Tags: vmware-vsphere, broadcom

I've got 4 Cisco UCS C210 M2 servers, each with a Broadcom NetXtreame II BCM5709 Quad-port adapter in it. They are all running vSphere 5.1 U1.

On one the servers, the Broadcom ports show up as both vmnics, as well as iSCSI HBAs. On the other 3, I only see the vmnics lists.

Anyone have a clue why they may be missing from the other servers, or how to turn it off on the first server? Don't really have a need to use the hardware offload functions, have been using the software iSCSI adapter without issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

We have this Broadcom NICs over here. All I can say is that this cards aren't 100% offload capable.

As example, they only offload the TCP stack. The iSCSI connection is at some point managed by the software.

So you should add an VMkernel connection with your iSCSI IP Address on the Virtual Switch of VMware. After this you'll be able to attach the Broadcom's as HBA hardware controller and directly add the LUNs.

I'm attaching a picture of our scenario:

[image: iSCSI Broadcom Configuration]

Try to add the VMkernel port, reboot ESXi, and share your results.

Comment: Vinicius, I think you are mis-understanding my question: I'm not looking for how to use the TCP offload. There's some configuration difference between my servers where one is offering the offload option, and the others aren't, and I can't figure out where it is.